# Class not found error when unmarshaling a class

Tags: android, android-widget, classnotfoundexception, parcelable

I'm building an Android widget and I tried to add clicking functionality to each one list item in the widget.
It works except I just somehow cant put intended Extras to the intent. When I try to put there my class Parallel which implements Parcalable interface, it gracefuly fails  with following error. Is there a possibility the widget itself somehow does not have access to the class? (its located in my Apps namespace and its public)

```
10-01 11:13:50.819  18503-18809/? E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: cz.cvut.kosapp.model.entities.Parallel
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.cvut.kosapp.model.entities.Parallel
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
    at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:302)
    at android.content.Intent.fillIn(Intent.java:6352)
    at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:210)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:2603)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:232)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1737)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cz/cvut/kosapp/model/entities/Parallel
    ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "cz.cvut.kosapp.model.entities.Parallel" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Parcelable` there's sometimes a weird issue where it cannot find the class between processes, maybe someone here can remind me why. In your `Parallel` model object that your passing around you should add an explicitly call the `getClassLoader()`.

so something like this...

```
protected Parallel(Parcel source) {
        super(source);

        // Explicitly get the class loader of this class as there is sometimes a
        // weird issue
        // when passing Parcel between processes
        Bundle data = source.readBundle(Parallel.class.getClassLoader());
        this.foo = data.getLong("foo");
        this.bar = data.getString("bar");
    }
```

Comment: Well..it did not help:/
Here is my code for both of those problematic classes..
https://gist.github.com/simekadam/6789724
https://gist.github.com/simekadam/6789727